# How to save a bounding box on an image?

Tags: front-end, image, image-processing

It's easy to save the coordinates of individual points, but for the life of me I can't seem to access the box's position and dimensions: {top, left, width, height}. How can I achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

After you draw one or more selection rectangles and click away from the image they are still there <s>suspended in a xenon mist</s> but they are only visible if you <s>look dead ahead</s> use the selection tool.  We can extract that data from the underlying Cell expression with this [`Button`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Button.html):

```
Button["Copy ImageMarkers", 
  Cases[
    NotebookRead[SelectedNotebook[]],
    _[ImageMarkers, val_] :> val,
    -1
  ] // CopyToClipboard
] // CreatePalette
```

First make a selection in the image:

[image]

Click **Cancel** in the Selection Tools dialog, but *leave the image itself selected*:

[image]

Click the Palette button generated earlier, then on the clipboard is:

> ```
> {{Rectangle[{54., 35.}, {240., 465.}], Rectangle[{132., 329.}, {465., 488.}]}}
> ```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to delete just one of the rectangles?

Comment: @M.R. Interactively or programmatically?

Comment: Well I had hoped to create a UI tool that loads a virtual stack of images to go through this process quickly for building machine learning training metadata sets, need the bounding box for every target object in every image. So both I think!